# WinInet and SOAP

Tags: windows-mobile, wininet

Hoi,

I tried to create a soap request using the WinInet API, however adding headers with SOAP etc seems to fail. Is this a known issue or can WinInet not be used for SOAP?

Any help or sample is highly appreciated.

Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Since WinInet can be used via P/Invoke from NETCF and you don't mention a preferred language, I liberally assume that's what you're doing. ;-)

Then I'd propose using NETCF directly instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2005/01/31/364279.aspx

Comment: I use C++ as language and the platform is Windows Mobile.